# Proving a more general variant of the inclusion-exclusion principle

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

There are several questions and answers about the inclusion-exclusion principle, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2376188/explanation-of-inclusion-and-exclusion-principle-formula), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475565/intuition-for-inclusion-exclusion-principle) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808129/generalised-inclusion-exclusion-principle).
Similarly, I found a lot of proofs, e.g. induction, comparing both sides, ... . There is another approach, however, that I grapple with at the moment:

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space and $A_i \in \mathcal{F}, i \in I = \{1, \ldots, n\}$. For $J \subset I$ define
$$S_J = \bigcap_{j \in J} A_j \cap \bigcap_{j \in I\setminus J} A_j^c$$

Apparently, one can show now that $\bigcap_{k \in K} A_k = \dot{\bigcup}_{K \subset J \subset I} S_J$ for all $K \subset I$.
This relation, especially the disjointness of the $S_J$ is not immediately clear to me formally.

Building on this result, one can then show that for all $J \subset I$ it holds that

$$ P(S_J) = \sum\limits_{K: J \subset K \subset I} (-1)^{\vert K \setminus J \vert} P(\bigcap_{k \in K} A_k) $$

Then, setting $J = \emptyset$, we recover the usual inclusion-exclusion principle.

Besides the clarification on the disjointness of the $S_J$, I would like to better grasp what is going on here in terms of intuition or visual representation.
The usual inclusion-exclusion principle is nicely illustrated with the help of Venn diagrams, for example, and how many times elements are counted on both sides of the equation.
In the above approach, I don't yet see visually how the definition of the $S_J$ fits in this framework of intersections and unions.

Comment: $S_J$ is the set of elements having _exactly_ the properties $A_j$ with $j\in J$ (and no others). $\cap_{k\in K}A_k$ is the set of elements with _at least_ the properties $A_k$ with $k\in K$ (and possibly others). So the exact set of properties of each of those elements has indices in some superset of $K$, i.e. in some set $J\subseteq I$ such that $K\subseteq J$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $\omega\in\Omega$ let $J(\omega)=\{j\in I:\omega\in A_j\}$, and note that $\omega\in S_{J(\omega)}$. In fact, $J(\omega)$ is the unique $J\subseteq I$ such that $\omega\in S_J$. To see this, let $J$ be any subset of $I$ different from $J(\omega)$, and suppose first that there is a $j\in J(\omega)\setminus J$. Then $\omega\in A_j$, so $\omega\notin\Omega\setminus A_j$; and by definition $S_J\subseteq\Omega\setminus A_j$, so $\omega\notin S_J$. Now suppose that there is a $j\in J\setminus J(\omega)$. Then $S_J\subseteq A_j$, but $\omega\in\Omega\setminus A_j$, so again $\omega\notin S_J$. Thus, $\omega\in J$ iff $J=J(\omega)$, and the sets $S_J$ are pairwise disjoint.

In fact each $S_J$ corresponds to one of the atomic regions in the Venn diagram. $S_\varnothing$, for instance, is the region outside all of the sets, and $S_I$ is the intersection of all of the sets. In a simple Venn diagram with $3$ sets, $A_1,A_2$, and $A_3$, $S_{\{1,3\}}$ is the set of points inside $A_1\cap A_3$ but outside $A_2$. Each of the atomic regions is uniquely identified by the collection of sets containing it: it is inside all of those and outside all of the rest.

Now suppose that $\omega\in\bigcap_{k\in K}A_k$. Then $K\subseteq J(\omega)$, and $\omega\in S_{J(\omega)}\subseteq\bigsqcup_{K\subseteq J\subseteq I}S_J$. Conversely, if $\omega\in\bigsqcup_{K\subseteq J\subseteq I}S_J$, then $K\subseteq J(\omega)$, and $\omega\in\bigcap_{k\in K}A_k$. Thus, $\bigcap_{k\in K}A_k=\bigsqcup_{K\subseteq J\subseteq I}S_J$.

Comment: @Taufi: I just showed that each $\omega\in\Omega$ belongs to exactly one of the sets $S_J$; that's exactly what it means for the sets $S_J$ to be pairwise disjoint (and in fact a partition of $\Omega$).

Comment: @Taufi: Yes. $$\begin{align*}S_{J_1}\cap S_{J_2}&=\big(A_1\cap A_2\cap(\Omega_\setminus A_3\big)\cap\big(A_2\cap A_3\cap(\Omega\setminus A_1\big)\\&=A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3\cap(\Omega\setminus A_1)\cap(\Omega\setminus A_3)\\&\subseteq A_1\cap(\Omega\setminus A_1)\\&=\varnothing\;.\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note added: This is exactly what Alexander explained in his comment, which I saw after posting my answer.

Here’s a way to think about the sets $S_J$.

First, buy a huge number of stickers with numbers $1$ through $n$ on them. Then go through each $x\in\Omega$ and put an $i$ sticker on $x$ for each event $A_i$ where $x\in A_i$. Call the “sticker-set” of $x$ the set of sticker numbers you put on $x$.

For a set of numbers $J$, the set $S_J$ contains those elements of $\Omega$ whose “sticker-set” is precisely $J$. This follows directly from the definition: $S_J$ contains (via the left intersection) only those elements $x$ that *do* have $j$-stickers on them for each $j\in J$ and (via the right intersection) that *do not* have $j$-stickers on them for each $j\notin J$.

The $S_J$ are disjoint, because each $x$ has a well-defined sticker-set.

The “apparently” equality is intuitive: The left side, $\bigcap_{k \in K} A_k$, is the set of $x$ that have a sticker for every $k\in K$ (but possibly some additional stickers). In other words, $\bigcap_{k \in K} A_k$ comprises the elements of $\Omega$ whose sticker-set is $K$ or a superset of $K$. That’s what the right hand side expresses.

Comment: If two different elements $x$ and $y$ have the same sticker-set (call that sticker-set $J$), then they are both in $S_J$, because $S_J$ is the set of elements with sticker-set $J$. Try this analogy. $P_{N}$ is the set of all people named $N$ (and assume every person has exactly one name). Can two people have the same name, but be in different $P_{N}$s? No. If one person is in $P_x$ and another is in $P_y$, and they have the same name, then $x=y=$their name. If two people are named $t$, they are both in $P_t$.